# Android. Выпадающее меню по клику на иконку

Tags: android, menu, popupmenu

Как можно сделать данную выпадающую менюшку в правом верхнем углу. Есть ли у кого нибудь уроки на данную тему?

[image: Как можно сделать данную выпадающую менюшку в правом верхнем углу]

в Место `Toast.makeText(FeedActivity.this, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` , хочу реализовать то что, написал @katso

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_filter:
            Toast.makeText(FeedActivity.this, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**popup_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  
    <item  
        android:id="@+id/one"  
        android:title="One"/>  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/two"  
        android:title="Two"/>  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/three"  
        android:title="Three"/>
</menu>
```

---

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button);           
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        popup.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Мне надо его сюда вписать, но таким методов вроде пробовал уже `@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_filter:
                Toast.makeText(FeedActivity.this, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }`

Comment: вместо `Toast.makeText(FeedActivity.this, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: я вышел понятнее написал.

Comment: @SatanistDevilov, не понятнее) объясните, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: ну всё тоже самое по клику на иконку. только иконка прописана в списке Menu item и по клику на ней чтоб вызывалось выпадающее меню. Выше описаны кейсы и в кейсе `case R.id.menu_filter: ........ return true;` хочу чтоб по клику он обрабатывал выпадающее меню.